# Binary Search Tree Access Violation on root node_ptr

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am getting "Unhandled exception at 0x00263ACB in Trees.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." on the first if statement of remove_node function. Can anyone give me a suggestion, I am stumped.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like `node_ptr` isn't initialized. Can you post the code where it supposedly gets initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error could be hidden here:
In both cases you go to the left child and at some point approach a leaf (and try to delete its child which doesn't exist). Try to replace one of `remove_node(num, node_ptr->left);` by `remove_node(num, node_ptr->right);`

Also it's a good idea to first check whether a node exists.

Comment: My apologies, I was confused that the error was coming from code further up the line. When I did modified the code where you suggested the error discontinued. Thank you very much!